# Eroor:F:/ReactNativeProject/FirstProject/index.android.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (23:8)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I take a simple reference to set two `TextView` and `ImageView` , when i compile it show the eroor `F:/ReactNativeProject/FirstProject/index.android.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (23:8)
  at F:\ReactNativeProject\FirstProject\index.android.js:23:8
onResponse
    DevServerHelper.java:330
execute
    RealCall.java:126
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587
run
    Thread.java:818`

Some one can teach me my code where is wrong?

```
import React, {  Component,} from 'react';
import {   AppRegistry,  Image,  StyleSheet,  Text,  View,} from 'react-native';

var MOKCKED_MOVIES_DATA=[
    {title:'Title' , year:'2017' , posters:{thumbnail:'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},
];


class SampleAppMovies extends Component{
render(){
    var movie=MOKCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
            <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri:movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                   style={styles.thumbnail}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

    var styles=StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            backgroundColor:'#F5FCFF',
        },
        thumbnail:{
            width:53,
            height:81,
        },
    });
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstProject', () => SampleAppMovies);
```

And the error doesn't show the code line , how do i find the error well when using React Native ?

Comment: It does show the error at `index.android.js:23:8`

Comment: What exactly is 23:8 ?  It means that code line at 23 ?

Comment: Line 23 and 8th character in index.android.js

Comment: Ok then... so my code line 23 is `var styles=StyleSheet.create({` and what's 8th character ?  Can you tell me ?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your responding , i find my error that is `}` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the style declaration out of component

```
import React, {  Component,} from 'react';
import {   AppRegistry,  Image,  StyleSheet,  Text,  View,} from 'react-native';

var MOKCKED_MOVIES_DATA=[
    {title:'Title' , year:'2017' , posters:{thumbnail:'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}},
];


class SampleAppMovies extends Component{
render(){
    var movie=MOKCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
            <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri:movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                   style={styles.thumbnail}
            />
        </View>
    );
} 
}

  var styles=StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            backgroundColor:'#F5FCFF',
        },
        thumbnail:{
            width:53,
            height:81,
        },
    });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstProject', () => SampleAppMovies);
```